# TypeScript TSLint "interface-name" not working in VSC

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, tslint

I would like to have the I letter prepend every interface name in TypeScript. Some time ago it started working. Added a rule to explicitly check for 'I'.

The *tslist.json* file looks like this:

```
{
  "defaultSeverity": "error",
  "extends": [
    "tslint:latest",
    "tslint-react",
    "tslint-config-prettier"
  ],
  "linterOptions": {
    "exclude": [
      "node_modules/**/*.ts"
    ]
  },
  "rules": {
    "no-console": false,
    "interface-name": [true, "always-prefix"]
  }
}
```

According to the docs - https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/interface-name/

What could be the issue? Using Visual Studio Code with a TSLint extension.

Answer (score 0):

My *tslist.json* file used:

```
"extends": [
  "tslint:latest",
  ...
  "tslint-config-prettier"
],
```

However my *package.json* file missed corresponding npm-package - https://www.npmjs.com/package/tslint-config-prettier.

The error could be clearly seen in VSC Output panel, saying Linter is missing a dependant module.

After installing *tslint-config-prettier*, TSLint compiler everything went back working as it should.